# Is it beneficial to load images onLoad consider from SEO perspective?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, image, responsive-design, seo

My web page is almost 2.5Mb in size, it loads 20 or 30 images ,Google Map, JCarausel plugins etc.
It uses resposive design. Page seems fast on desktop but there are several issues when browsed from smartphones.

First is performance issue. It is slow because all the images and scripts have to be loaded but there is design issue also because all the images are loaded then JCarausel script is called which causes that all the images are spread across the web page and after JCarausel is called only few are showed and the rest are hidden.

So far I did this:

1. On server side I have handler which can make image smaller depending on Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice property, but there has to be compromise between quality and image size.
2. To solve design problem, I tried to load images onload. (Change src attribute with data-src which is filled on server)

My questions is this:
Is it considered cloaking to serve images for desktop users and not for mobile users (the same page, same URL)? Will images be indexed? They are loaded in "normal" way for desktop users.
What would be best practise in these situations?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: @John Is it about performance also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is *not* considered cloaking. Many Web sites serve targeted content based on device or other parameters. According to Google:

> Sites that dynamically serve all devices on the same set of URLs, but each URL serves different HTML (and CSS) depending on whether the user agent is a desktop or a mobile device

Is a supported Web site configuration. See ["Building Smartphone-Optimized Websites"](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/smartphone-sites/details).

GoogleBot does not execute the JavaScript on your Web site, so the images served in this manner will not be indexed. Your configuration is fine as-is. It is only suboptimal for very, very small portion of visitors with JavaScript disabled, or expect images to load with it disabled.

Comment: Thanks Jacob. If I understand you, my pictures will be indexed (more quality photos, because they are server for desktop users) but not low quality photos. This is ok with me. I think I was not clear enough. Only for mobile users (server side checking) I do Javascript code. Desktop users not run Javacript code (or they run, but it is not important because src attribute is populated for them.)

Comment: Another solution is to populate src attribute( load them like GoogleBot would load them, in "normal" way for mobile users also but only first 3 or four images.

Comment: Any HTML served by your site, including images referenced with a traditional `src` (`<img src="image.jpg">`), will be indexed by GoogleBot. So, yes, if you're serving images "normally" on desktop, Google will be able to find them.

Answer (score 0):

It's only bad to hide keyword stuffing & the likes.  It is beneficial to make a fast site.  Google has a channel on youtube that explains a lot of what they like to see in a site, googlewebstertools I think is the channel name.